# Should chat have TeX support?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, chat, user-scripts

OK, so [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) is now available... but; it has been suggested that for Mathematics we should have TeX support.

The current TeX processing has some non-trivial client impact. Before I even attempt trying to hack this in, is this something that the community would want / use?

(this would only apply to maths rooms, and would presumably only apply to posts written with what is, for other sites, the fixed-font indent - i.e 4 spaces)

Comment: Well first of all, there currently aren't that many users of that chat room. Unless more people show up to use it, $\TeX$-ing it up may well end up to be a waste of your time.

Comment: We were just now lamenting the lack of TeX support in chat.  Would it be possible to reconsider this?

Comment: Half a year has passed after the comment by @Glen. If there are any news? Chat still seem to have a lack of TeX support.

Comment: My old comment is now irremediably false, as there's now a bunch of us discussing math and a bunch of other stuff animatedly on chat...

Comment: Is there anyone who is enough of a coding wizard that can put things together into a working [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script that continually re-TeXs the page? Having to click a bookmark is crazy when things like [this script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/108770) exist and don't require clicking anywhere for it to work.

Comment: Corresp. feature request: [Why is there no support for MathJax in chat?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15041/)

Comment: There is a user script now; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220976/156248). (I tried to post this as an answer, but it was auto-converted. Huh.)

Comment: Is or how is mathjax available for mobiles?

Answer (score 133):

There are four bookmarks which are located on [this installation page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html):

1. `start ChatJax` installs [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) and starts a loop that renders $\LaTeX$ as needed.
   This is intended for use in chat, where the contents of the page are not static.
   Reloading the page will stop the loop, so the bookmark needs to be run again.
2. `render MathJax` installs MathJax and renders $\LaTeX$ once per execution.
   This is intended for use on web pages where the contents of the page are static.
3. `rendering off` disables MathJax while editing. This is useful when rendering is slow while editing questions and answers.
4. `rendering on` enables MathJax after being disabled by `rendering off`.

To get the bookmarks mentioned above, go to [this installation page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html).

There is a section at the bottom of the installation page to install ChatJax on a browser that cannot add bookmarks using drag-and-drop or a contextual menu. This is how I installed ChatJax on my iPhone.

If you are still having trouble installing on an iOS device, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164612) on Ask Different.

---

**[On April 30, 2017, the MathJax CDN will be shutting down.](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/)**

The bookmarks listed above will need to be reinstalled. I have updated the bookmarks to use the CDN at `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`. Make sure you reload [this installation page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) so that the new bookmarks are not hidden behind a stale cache.

Comment: I would nominate you to a [Hacker badge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/) if I could.

Comment: @Asaf: It's okay, I got a Necromancer badge for this answer. :-)

Comment: To get automatic processing, register the code above as a callback to the global AJAX complete event: `$('html').ajaxComplete(function() { ... });` Warning: this is just a hack and will cause MathJax to be reloaded on each use.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks! I have added your automatic processing addition.

Comment: [Here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95745) is how to handle the bookmark bar in Chrome. Create an empty bookmark, copy all of the text above starting with "javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax'" into the destination for a bookmark in the bar.

Comment: How persistent is the (Cloudfront) site hosting MathJax.js?

Comment: @Willie: if you are asking about "d3eoax9i5htok0", [this](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https) explains the weird domain name.

Comment: @robjohn: thanks. That's precisely what I was wondering about. BTW: thanks for the bookmark!

Comment: **Alert!** Linux and Windows versions have different bookmarking with Google Chrome but the combo **SHIFT+CTRL+B** should show you the bookmark -bar.

Comment: @Willie: the cloudfront.net url seems to be down, so I am switching to the mathjax.org url since that is what the main site uses.

Comment: For some odd reason, single `$...$` -thing does not work in Twitter but the double `$$...$$` -thing works, odd, investigating...

Comment: note to myself: click on Firefox bookmark whenever I enter math chat

Comment: @Theta30 I bet some [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)ing could save you that click

Comment: Does this only work for SE or any website?

Comment: The `render MathJax` and `start ChatJax` bookmarks will work on any website. The `rendering off` and `rendering on` bookmarks only work on websites that use MathJax.

Comment: "COPY TO CLIPBOARD link on pastebin.com" does there still exist such a link?

Comment: @Theta33: It now appears as [an icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ExcfC.png) to the top left of the text.

Comment: I used mathjax(added all four to my bookmark toolbar) and also greasemonkey(added it to firefox and then in preferences I included the chat pages) but non of them worked for me. Most probably I'm missing something but I don't know what?. I'm getting it hard to discuss any question in chat room. If somebody help me then that would be great for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Singh: If you install the "start ChatJax" bookmark, either in a menu or on the bookmark bar, you should be able to execute it (select it from the menu or click on it in the bookmark bar) while the chat window is active and then the LaTeX should continuously render until the page is refreshed (then you need to execute the bookmark again).

Comment: @robjohn Sir how to install? I just right clicked and then then clicked on `Bookmark This link` then added it to main bookmark. But this does not work. What steps I have to follow in order to install it?

Comment: @Singh: Method 1: drag the link from the installation page to the bookmark bar. Method 2: right-click on the link on the installation page and choose "Bookmark This Link".

Comment: @robjohn Sir thank you very much the `1` method worked for me. Now I can also work during chat. Thanks again.

Comment: The link to "all versions here" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Did you try the links at the top? The links in the original post are old.

Comment: @robjohn, sorry, I thought the section labeled "Update" was the latest version.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: I have removed the original post. It probably causes more confusion than necessary.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the links for the [chemistry enabled chatjax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3625/24750) also on the installation page? It seems to be a pain to install the bookmarklet without having a link to click on in some browsers; in firefox pasting the code to go to the page and then bookmarking it seems to instead search for the code in google.

Answer (score 17):

**Revision 3.** This one actually has a working loop, and uses jQuery instead of directly injecting a script element.

---

Unfortunately, it seems that new chat messages no longer trigger the ajaxComplete event, so my hack has to be replaced with a different one. This one runs MathJax on a 1-second cycle.

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bif(window.MathJax===undefined)%7BjQuery.getScript(%22http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML%22,function()%7BMathJax.Hub.Config(%7B%22HTML-CSS%22:%7BpreferredFont:%22TeX%22,availableFonts:%5B%22STIX%22,%22TeX%22%5D,linebreaks:%7Bautomatic:true%7D,EqnChunk:MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile?10:50%7D,tex2jax:%7BinlineMath:%5B%5B%22$%22,%22$%22%5D,%5B%22%5C%5C%5C%5C(%22,%22%5C%5C%5C%5C)%22%5D%5D,displayMath:%5B%5B%22$$%22,%22$$%22%5D,%5B%22%5C%5C%5B%22,%22%5C%5C%5D%22%5D%5D,processEscapes:true,ignoreClass:%22tex2jax_ignore%7Cdno%22%7D,TeX:%7BnoUndefined:%7Battributes:%7Bmathcolor:%22red%22,mathbackground:%22#FFEEEE%22,mathsize:%2290%25%22%7D%7D%7D,messageStyle:%22none%22%7D);MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();theLoop=function()%7BMathJax.Hub.Queue(%5B%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub%5D);window.setTimeout(theLoop,1e3)%7D;theLoop()%7D)%7Delse%7BMathJax.Hub.Queue(%5B%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub%5D)%7D%7D)()
```

---

Source code:

```
(function () {
    if (window.MathJax === undefined) {
        jQuery.getScript('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML', function () {
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
                "HTML-CSS": {
                    preferredFont: "TeX",
                    availableFonts: ["STIX", "TeX"],
                    linebreaks: {
                        automatic: true
                    },
                    EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50)
                },
                tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [
                        ["$", "$"],
                        ["\\\\(", "\\\\)"]
                    ],
                    displayMath: [
                        ["$$", "$$"],
                        ["\\[", "\\]"]
                    ],
                    processEscapes: true,
                    ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno"
                },
                TeX: {
                    noUndefined: {
                        attributes: {
                            mathcolor: "red",
                            mathbackground: "#FFEEEE",
                            mathsize: "90%"
                        }
                    }
                },
                messageStyle: "none"
            });

            MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();

            theLoop = function () {
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
                window.setTimeout(theLoop, 1000);
            };
            theLoop();
        });
    } else {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 12):

There is [ChatJax++](https://github.com/vyznev/chatjax) now, a user script that enables MathJax in SE chat in a smart way, i.e. it requires no user interaction and renders new messages automatically.

Answer (score 8):

For those of us who struggle to get ChatJax running on an iPad, you need to fake it into a bookmarklet that you can copy and paste into the Safari URL line, then save as a bookmark. Make an .html file on your desktop that you will save, put in Dropbox, and open with Safari on your iPad.

That .html file should have a textbox in it that you can copy here (go into *edit* mode):

**ChatJax Bookmarklet** 

COPY AND PASTE ROBJOHN'S SCRIPT HERE

Comment: We can no longer edit your answer to get the textbox because community Wiki answers cannot be edited.

Answer (score 6):

With MathJax 2.x the way to load it dynamically has changed and [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html) says that one should use a new method.

It seems to me that it ought to be possible to turn this into a [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script that runs automatically when receiving new input.