# How can I display LaTex with iPad in Chat?

Tags: support, mathjax, chat, ipad

This is the solution in Desktop [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), but I want to do it in iPad. How can I display LaTex in iPad's chat?

Comment: Are you using a mobile browser on iPad, or are you using the iOS app?