# LaTeX problem in RSS feed

Tags: support, mathjax, rss

Recently, I added the Mathematics SE RSS feed to a RSS reader. All questions written with $\LaTeX$ just show the code and not the symbols they are supposed to show.

What should I do so that the feeds in my RSS service show the questions in a readable form? Can you please help me?

Comment: This seems hard to fix. Latex on the site is rendered using MathJax (but also onsite). RSS readers don't pass on javascript, and thus won't 'pass on' MathJax. So you might have to pre-filter your rss feed to convert math to images or something. Or, hopefully, find an rss reader that already does this for you.

Comment: You have any suggestions for such rss service? Or if you can help me out by speaking to some of yuors friends who use rss feeds of this site?

Answer (score 1):

If your rss reader supports javascript bookmarklets, try installing [`render MathJax`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297). Every time you come across a page with MathJax on it, select the bookmarklet and the page should render.

If the feeds update periodically (that is, the content is not static), install [`start ChatJax`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297) instead.