# Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing - editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, markdown-preview, editor, user-scripts

I've only done a few questions here but already it's grinding on me. Why can't we have the writing-answer panel and the preview panel side by side, rather than below, this means for big answers I can't make use of the preview! It'd be great if side by side, two scroll-bars, or even a pop out (I have a window manager that gives me an always-on-top button :)) but this may not help those 'less fortunate' when it comes to OS.

It'd also be great if the preview wasn't trying to update EVERY keystroke, I'd love to have (the option, as I can see others disagreeing) an update button, or only when I pressed enter. Maybe only try and update everything after the last parsed expression (rather than the entire messages)

It can get QUITE laggy. So please please do this, or have like a profile option to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this has come up in the past. Searching meta (notably the tags [meta-tag:tex] and [meta-tag:markdown-preview]) brings up [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9736/43351).

Comment: I would hope so! I'm shocked it wasn't already implemented! I hate not being able to see what I'm writing because my answer is so long the preview is off the bottom of the screen - regardless of how close the bottom of the input box is to the top.

Comment: I agree with the laggy-ness. It is annoying. However, I find the placing of the preview box to be less of an issue, as I only look at this once I am finished (or once I have done some considerable typing). It is a check before posting rather than a constant aid, if that makes sense?

Comment: The problem with making two feature requests in one question is that people start voting to close if just one of them is a duplicate.

Comment: @RahulNarain I'm really sorry, it was my first one, I'm fairly new, is there a way I can separate them? Should I ask people don't downvote if they don't like one?

Comment: Just edit one of the feature requests out of this question, and ask it in a separate question.

Comment: A more descriptive title would help. I doubt that someone knows what this post is about just from reading the title: *Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing*. In fact this title does not tell me anything more than it is a ([meta-tag:feature-request]).

Comment: At meta.SO there is this feature-request: [Question and preview might be better side-by-side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70703/question-and-preview-might-be-better-side-by-side).

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2245/stack-exchange-side-by-side-edit-and-preview

Comment: I really do wish this feature was implemented, anyone have any links on progress/response from developers?

Comment: One workaround I've found is to type out question on stackedit.io which _is_ side-by-side, then copy/paste into MSE when done.

Answer (score 9):

I've been contributing to a userscript which adds side-by-side editing functionality to Stack Exchange. It can be toggled on and off by clicking a new button in the editor and works when writing new as well as editing existing questions and answers.

### Screenshot

[image: editor on the left, preview on the right]

**[More info can be found over at StackApps SE.](https://stackapps.com/q/6461/36263)**

Comment: There have been [other userscripts](http://stackapps.com/q/2245/36263) which implement this, but the Stack Exchange site code has changed so much that they no longer work.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you use ChatJax or not in chat, look at the bookmarks described in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297). The `rendering off` and `rendering on` bookmarks will turn off and on the MathJax rendering. While off, this prevents the rendering from affecting your typing.

Comment: I want some rendering though, just not every keystroke!

Comment: With the bookmarks in the bookmark bar, it only takes one click to turn MathJax rendering on or off. Otherwise, I guess you'll have to continue to nudge the developers.

Comment: So with these, you can effectively control how often it renders while composing a question/answer?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: yes. If I click on and off while MathJax is rendering, my browser gets confused, so I let the rendering finish before turning it back off.