# Firefox plugin to show edit and preview panels side by side

Tags: support, editor, user-scripts

I have installed a Firefox plugin many years ago that used Greasemonkey to allow to show editor and previewer panels side by side on MathExchange (maybe other Exchanges as well).

After I reset Firefox I lost it and have been trying to search it for longer than two hours and I can't find it. I found a few posts on SE meta on the topic "preview on the right" but those posts are pretty old and are not actually pointing to a solution I was looking for.

Could someone please let me know where I can get it? Thanks.

Comment: This [Stack Apps page](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) has a link to [Stack Exchange Side-by-side Edit and Preview](https://stackapps.com/questions/2245/stack-exchange-side-by-side-edit-and-preview).  It says however that it is "broken at the moment".

Comment: @hardmath Thanks!

Comment: If you're okay with 3rd-party tool, then [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io) might interest you.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. Actually I have already tried it before I posted this, but the problem I had with it was that I couldn't figure out how to make \\begin{align} \\end{align} on it. I will try to figure out.

Comment: An answer to [older feature request on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/feature-request-but-it-woudnt-be-a-feature-itd-be-a-blessing-editing-pane) has a link to [script on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6461/obsolete-see-the-sox-post-side-by-side-editing). However, it is shown with the warning: "This script no longer works and is no longer supported.  See [the *Stack Overflow Extras* (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) for this functionality." You can check whether SOX might be useful for you.

Comment: StackEdit runs KaTex, which has some minor differences to Mathjax that are very annoying. For example, (1) one can only use `aligned` and no `align` (2) one cannot do equation hyperlink via `\tag` and `\ref` (3) one cannot use `\require` to load packages or `\newcommand` to define macros..... The list goes on.

Comment: Some convenient formatting that can be done here are in html or java, which is absent in StackEdit (and the Markdown commands there is incomplete). I tried for a while but ended up not using StackEdit except for answers longer than, say, 5000 characters with LOTS of equations.

Comment: [StackApps post #6091](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) has a powerful app, and there's an answer addressing issues with Firefox.