# Can we have the suggested questions' titles parsed by default?

Tags: bug, mathjax, asking-questions, titles, editor

The suggested questions' titles here are not parsed:

[image]

I find this a bit odd, because they are indeed parsed in other scenarios, like this:

[image]

Why aren't the titles parsed when suggesting questions? I think it would be very useful to have them parsed by default.

Comment: There was some other instance where titles didn't parse... Hm.. let me try to remember.. **Edit:** Ah yes, it is when you switch tabs in your answers/questions: [this picture shows it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zuK6w.jpg). I switched from the *newest* tab to the *votes* tab.

Comment: (This might be related but...probably not). Previously tag wikis were not parsed when you mouse-oever-ed them. However, this was because it took too long to complete before the pop-up popped. MathJax is now fast enough for this not to matter, so it is rendered when you mouse over now. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/latex-in-tag-wikis).

Comment: So, this has potential to be a feature request?

Comment: @Omega Most certainly. I'd consider it a great feature, even though there already exists a workaround.

Comment: (Bump) I'd like to insist on having this feature! The workaround is good, but there's no reason to not have this by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've included a fix for this issue in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.2.  It turns out to be very simple — I just need to tell MathJax to re-typeset the titles after they're loaded via AJAX.  The code that does this in SOUP is:

```
hookAjax( /^\/search\/titles\b/, function () {
    typeof(MathJax) !== 'undefined' &&
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'question-suggestions']);
} );
```

where `hookAjax()` is a wrapper around `$.ajaxSuccess()` that I use to inject code into the SE framework's AJAX handling.

ps. The next version will also include a fix for the related issue on the user profile page [pointed out by Karl Kronenfeld in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/41671).  I missed that comment originally, which is why it's not in v.1.2.0 yet.

Comment: I can't really believe that after $5$ whole years, this still hasn’t been done. Would you please be so kind as to add the `bug` tag to the question?

Comment: [Done.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11036/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Robjohn Chatjax links to parse it. You can get it here:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/19341

Clicking "start Chatjax" after you entered your title get's you

[image]

And as an extra, it even works at the [arxiv](http://xxx.lanl.gov/list/math/new)...