# MathJax broken by font clash in Related Questions and Hot Meta questions under new responsive design

Tags: bug, mathjax, design, font

We used to ren­der the Re­lat­ed Ques­tions and the Hot Me­ta Ques­tion lists in
Geor­gia so that they looked right when com­bined with Math­Jax. Now we don’t,
and it looks... sub­op­ti­mal (i.e., weird, wrong, broken):

[image: mathjax bad render demo 1]

[image: mathjax bad render demo 2]

No­tice how that’s the wrong "2" in "2-el­e­ment" and the 
wrong "3" in "3 ques­tions". It’s al­so ***much too big a dig­it*** in both cas­es.

This looks even worse when more Math­Jax is in­volved:

[image: mathjax bad render demo 3]

That just doesn’t look good now; it looks like a mis­take.
You shouldn’t be mix­ing sans and serif faces: that should
all be set in serif [like it used to be](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23073/25361).

<sub><sub>Drat! [This ancient bug](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11036/25361) ***still*** isn’t fixed after five years now.</sub></sub>

Comment: Tangentially, the 3 should not be in MathJax at all. Likely it should not even be a symbol, but maybe that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @quid There is that. :) I’d’ve written it out as *three* myself.