# Why is there no support for MathJax in chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mathjax, chat

The question [Should chat have TeX support](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/15040)  was first asked
3½ years ago, and  it has been asked at intervals since then.  I am not asking that question.  I *know* that chat should have TeX support and so does everyone else.  My questions are, **why hasn't this been done** and **when will it be done**?  The lack of MathJax support in chat is a serious problem with the site, and it should be fixed as soon as possible, preferably today.

I am aware of the existing solutions such as greasemonkey scripts.  I use them myself.  They do not solve the problem because while they allow one to *receive* formatted mathematics, they don't allow one to *send* it, unless the recipient *also* has a script installed.  But in general I can't expect the person I am talking to will have one installed. Then I think I am sending “No, you need to consider $\int_0^\infty \def\O{\mathcal O} \O\left(\operatorname{erf}(\frac x2)\right)\;dx$” but the hapless loser I am trying to help only sees “No, you need to consider \int_0^\infty \def\O{\mathcal O} \O\left(\operatorname{erf}(\frac x2)\right)\;dx”.

When a discussion goes on in comments, SE posts a notice telling the people involved to take the discussion to chat:

[image: screenshot of notice]

That sounds great at first, but it is completely unhelpful, because if the discussion is taken to chat, you will no longer be able to actually discuss mathematics.  And the prior discussion, imported automatically, will look like this to the person you are trying to help:

[image: sample chat with symbols unrendered]

It seems to me completely obvious that this feature is crucial, and its lack should have been addressed years ago, and yet it has not been.  So I repeat: **What is causing the delay on this**?  When will this be fixed?  And if it's been decided for some reason that it will never happen, then what is going to be done instead? What's the point of having chat at all, when it doesn't work? The purpose of the site is to ask and answer questions about mathematics, and the only purpose of chat is to support that. Other features of the site assume that it will.  But in its present form, it does not and it cannot.

Comment: You're kidding right? There is TeX support, ChatJAX, provided by robjohn. It is as simple as pasting a button to the toolbar and clicking it to render the code.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Do you think you could read as far as paragraph 2 before you post ill-considered comments? I have such a button in my toolbar, and I click it when necessary, but I can't paste it into the toolbar of the person I am talking to, or click it to render *my* code for *them*, which is what is really needed.

Comment: I think the current method of using a user script is the worst of both worlds, new users in chat only see TeX source which looks rather ugly, and anyone actually using the chat will still have to pay the performance penalty of MathJax. I'm also pretty sure that there is currently no plan by SE to implement this, so I'd suggest that one of the Math mods points an SE community team member to this post once clear community support is evident.

Comment: To some extent, this is because that ChatJax script solved the problem back when there was someone seemingly interested of making a permanent solution.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem; it only solves a visible but small part of the problem. Experienced users can use it to exchange mathematical messages amongst themselves, and these are the people who are most vocal.

Comment: @Mjd I'm sorry for flipping. Why don't you think ChatJAX isn't a solution? When new users arrive we can just tell them how things work. :)

Comment: Back in my chat days, the channel was small enough for it to be a nice temporary solution, and there weren't many rooms for this to be a problem. I don't know how large the main chatroom is, but it seems that there are more rooms, in particular due to the "automatic chat" feature. So I agree this can no longer constitute as a proper solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: double negative?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: ChatJax works in any chatroom. However, when a Q&A comment thread is moved to a private chatroom, ChatJax would indeed be useless if neither party knows about it. I think that SE is hesitant about supporting MathJax in chat because there are only a very small number of rooms that would use it, and in the Mathematics chatroom ChatJax seems to work well. The biggest inconvenience is starting ChatJax when the page is newly opened or is reset.

Comment: @rob: I know very well that ChatJax works in every chatroom, in fact in any webpage (and I have used that fact before). But my point was exactly that not everyone is aware of that script and how to use it.

Comment: @robjohn I'd guess that enabling MathJax on the whole SE chat won't ever happen. But if it is technically possible, I think enabling it only for certain rooms, or all rooms associated with certain sites, could be possible.

Comment: @MJD: Wouldn't this be more a [meta-tag:feature-request] than a [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: @robjohn IMHO, it is a bug when the system suggest something (moving  discussion to chat) that didn't work.

Comment: @robjohn I think I stated my reasons for why this is a bug, but I will try to make them clearer. This web site has exactly one purpose, which is to provide a platform for asking and answering questions about mathematics. Every feature of the site is intended to advance that purpose. The chat system was added so that querents and respondents could discuss the questions and answers that are about mathematics.  But it cannot be used effectively for this without both users installing additional software in their browsers. Therefore, it is not fulfilling its sole purpose, and that is a bug.

Comment: The ability to enable MathJax in chat literally does not exist right now (as far as I'm aware). I'm coming down on the side of "feature request" here.

Comment: I find it especially odd that nothing was done as the person asking the question seemed to be asking *from a vaguely official position*. As in, it was almost StackExchange itself asking the question!

Comment: I think performance issue may occur when latex is enabled in instant messaging

Comment: Performance doesn't matter if the software is completely unable to perform its core function. It doesn't matter how efficiently Math SE Chat can be used to discuss the weather or the World Cup, because this site is not about those subjects. It can't be used to discuss mathematics, so it is not performing its core function, and any efficiency gained thereby is wasted.

Comment: @user1729PhD: Anna only edited. The original post was by MJD.

Comment: @WillieWong I think User1729 is talking about the 3½-year-old post [Should chat have TeX support?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/15040), which appears to have been asked by a SE employee.

Comment: @MJD SE is extremely conservative with regards to performance, and MathJax has a large performance impact. This performance impact is certainly worth it on pages where it is actively used, but loading MathJax when it is not used would be a considerable waste. I don't know if the option to insert JS only in specific chat room exist, but that would be a requisite for enabling MathJax in my opinion. Adding a performance penalty for users that don't use MathJax would not be acceptable to SE from what I know.

Comment: @MadScientist My guess is that you're right, and the math chat room would have to be distinguished from other chats if it were to automatically load MathJax, as after all this wouldn't be useful in most (any?) other SE chat rooms.  Still, maybe we could get the ChatJax script integrated into the sidebar as a button or preference, so that users could elect to turn it on and off as they choose. This would be more newbie-friendly than the current solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I have been using the chat system for 2 years and I didn't know about the MathJax script. I thought people were just copying and pasting it into forms to see the rendered output. There should at the very minimum be a notice put on the page about enabling this MathJax script. Preferably, MathJax should be supported by default on the chatrooms of SE sites that require it such as this one.

Comment: @sonicboom I take it by "using the chat system" you mean with the "take this discussion to chat" feature, instead of the main hub we use for general discussion. Not to disagree that mathjax should be taken care of by the system and not the users, and that other rooms are different, but as a general rule whenever someone asks about the latex in our room we direct them to the script, and for quite some time now I've personally (along with robjohn) pinned a notice on the starboard directing users to the script. I also have sparsely seen you in chat (I actually don't remember you).

Comment: mind you, Zulip allows MathJax globally, noone complains it slows things down. Maybe SF should look at how it's done there - Zulip is open-source...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really relish being the bearer of bad news, but here's [a recent answer by Shog9 on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261528):

> This request was discussed by the team on April 9th, 2014. The potential rendering cost would be such that it would need to be a per-room *and* per-user option; this would then create a situation where users would potentially never be sure how their messages would look to other readers - in other words, little better than the user-script solution currently available.

Comment: Well, just like the solution for the site itself is simple - On for all users, one should do it in Chat Room as well. Otherwise no one would move comments to Chat Room.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer the following piece of information about trying to tweak chatjax to work on the chat page.

Usually sites enable Mathjax by using javascript in their global header, so having specific options for certain pages doesn't work well with this configuration.

That is, trying to have chatjax work as specific option on the chat page would probably conflict with the global header.

My hypothesis on the delay would be trying to figure out how to have page specific options in Mathjax not conflict with the global configuration. I don't know the inner workings of the site but that is my guess.

Comment: The MathJax script config options are injected on each page, so there's no technical reason why we couldn't have MathJax support only in some chat rooms and not in others. A natural choice would be to only enable it in chat rooms that are associated with SE sites that use MathJax on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox like me, then using this script on Greasemonkey add-on may fix the issue perfectly. To install this script just click on "New user script" in the add-on then copy and paste this as it is.

````
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 781864
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var stop = false;
var update = true;

if(window.MathJax === undefined)
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML";
    var config='MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { ' +
               'webFont: "TeX", ' +
               'preferredFont: "TeX", ' + 
               'availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], ' +
               'linebreaks: { automatic:true }, '+
               'EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, ' +
               'tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno|last-message" }, ' +
               'TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js", "enclose.js", "cancel.js"], noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%25" } } }, ' +
               'messageStyle: "none"}); ' +
               'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

    if(window.opera) {
        script.innerHTML = config;
    } else {
        script.text = config;
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    $('#chat-buttons').prepend('<button class="button" id="math-button">MathJax</button>');
 $('#math-button').click(function() {
        $('body').append('<div id="jax-popup-bg" class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.5; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>' +
                         '<div id="jax-popup" style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: block; padding: 10px; position: fixed; width: 150px; z-index: 1001; margin-top: -93.5px; margin-left: -113px;" class="wmd-prompt-dialog">' +
                             '<div align="center">' +
                                 '<b>MathJax</b><br>' + 
                                 'Interval:' +
                                 '<input type="text" id="jax-heartbeat" style="width: 80px; margin-left: 10px" title="In miliseconds" value="' + beatInterval + '"/><br>' +
                                 '<input type="checkbox" id="jax-update" title="Use an ajax handler instead of a heartbeat">Update</input>' +
                                 '<input type="checkbox" id="jax-disable" style="margin-left: 10px" title="Temporarily stops MathJax from updating">Disable</input>' +
                             '</div>' +

                             '<button id="jax-ok" class="button">Ok</button>' +
                             '<button id="jax-cancel" style="margin-left: 10px" class="button">Cancel</button>' +
                             '<script type="text/javascript">' +
                                 '$("#jax-update").prop("checked", update);' +
         '$("#jax-disable").prop("checked", stop);' +
                                 '$("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", !update || stop);' +
         '$("#jax-update").prop("disabled", stop);' +

                                 '$("#jax-ok").click(function() {' +
          'if($.isNumeric($("#jax-heartbeat").val()) && parseInt($("#jax-heartbeat").val()) >= 1000) {' +
           'if($("#jax-update").prop("checked") && !$("#jax-disable").prop("checked")) {' +
            'beatInterval = parseInt($("#jax-heartbeat").val());' +
                                         '}' +

                                         'if(!$("#jax-disable").prop("checked")) {' +
            'update = $("#jax-update").prop("checked");' +
                                         '}' +

                                         'stop = $("#jax-disable").prop("checked");' +
           '$("#jax-popup").remove();' +
                                         '$("#jax-popup-bg").remove();' +
                                     '} else {' +
                                         'alert("Values must be numeric and no less than 1000");' +
                                     '}' +
                                 '});' +

                                 '$("#jax-cancel").click(function() {' +
          '$("#jax-popup").remove();' +
          '$("#jax-popup-bg").remove();' +
                                 '});' +

                                 '$("#jax-update").click(function() {' +
          '$("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", !$("#jax-update").prop("checked"));' +
                                 '});' +

                                 '$("#jax-disable").click(function() {' +
          '$("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", $("#jax-disable").prop("checked"));' +
          '$("#jax-update").prop("disabled", $("#jax-disable").prop("checked"));' +
                                 '});' +
                             '</script>' +
                         '</div>');
    });
} else {
    if(window.MathJax !== undefined)
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
}

$('document').ready(function() {
    beat();
});

$('html').ajaxComplete(function() {
    if(!update && !stop)
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
});

var beatInterval = 5000;
function beat() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        if(window.MathJax !== undefined)
        {
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);

            $.each($('script[type="math/tex"]'), function(index, value) { 
                if ($(value).parent().data('events') === undefined) { 
     $(value).parent().click(function() { 
      if ($(value).parent().html().split($(value).html() || []).length - 1 === 1) {
       $(value).parent().append(' \\$' + $(value).html() + '\\$');
                        }
                    }); 
                } 
            });
        }

        if(update && !stop)
            beat();

    }, beatInterval);
};
```
````