# MathJax in discussion/chat

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, chat

When one moves comments to a discussion/chat it seems like MathJax won't work. This is unfortunate since it could discourage users to move the discussion to the chat.

Note that explanation elsewhere on how to make this work, in places that are hard to find does not help much. It's quite likely that the user remains in the perception that it simply doesn't work.

Preferably it should work without the user having to do anything special at all to make it work.

If that's not possible the information should at least be more accessible - that is where the chat is (when moving discussion from comments to chat). One could even detect the presence of MathJax markup and show the link only then. Preferably here one should make it so that the user only have to select to enable ChatJax only once if possible.

Comment: You should search for ChatJax (on this very meta).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, it leads me to the impression that this will not be fixed and I should rely on installing some bookmarks that's to be found on a broken link. Quite disappointing, but perhaps that's the truth...

Comment: It seems that the request to implement this directly in StackExhange chat (i.e., without use of some userscript or bookmarklet) was declined: [Why is there no support for MathJax in chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15041) 
(If this is what you are asking about. Your post is a bit unclear - the word "anymore" suggests that you are talking about something which used to work before.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, with "anymore" I made the assumption that it have had worked. To me it seems so obvious that it should have worked so I didn't consider the possibility that it had never worked...

Comment: The problem with userscripts is that it may not be that obvious for an averagege user. I see references to this script, but the link I've found was broken. How is a user expected to find this solution if he (1) don't know that it exist (2) when informed that it exist can't find it because of broken link? How likely then is it that the one I chat with have that script installed? One can at least not make that assumption...

Comment: If you are referring to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) it contains this link which seems to be working: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html (There is also link to dropbox, which does not work for me. Perhaps you can ping robjohn in a comment or in chat to let him know about that problem. But probably he plans to change the bookmarklet anyway, because of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26118/mathjax-cdn-cdn-mathjax-org-will-be-shutting-down).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, that's the answer. Still the problem is for an average user to find that remains. Isn't there a way to somehow include that script in the chat? I mean the chances a normal user by chance finds that answer and opts to select the second link to the installation page seem quite small.

Comment: Well, if you talk to a user who is unaware of the bookmarklet, you can simply provide them the link. In the main chat room, the link is included in the [room description](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) - but I suppose many users did not notice that. (But it seems we have digressed from your original question - which after the clarification in the comments seem to be duplicate or reiteration of another feature request on this meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, but that description don't show up when you move a discussion from comments to chat. However wouldn't it be possible to somehow enable this automatically? Note that even though one can tell one that is unaware of that it obviously haven't happened - nobody have told me this before. Clearly it's quite easy to be unaware of that the user can make it work, and how to do it...