# Why is ChatJax not enabled by default?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, chat

There is a [ChatJax bookmark](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) for rendering LaTeX in chat. Why is it not run by default when math chatrooms are loaded? I find two issues with the current approach:

1. New users are not aware that they have to add this bookmark and run it whenever they enter a chat room. Instead, they are confronted with raw LaTeX code.
2. It is very annoying to have to manually run it *every single time* I enter chat.

Why is LaTeX not rendered by default in chat, like it is on questions and answers?

Comment: +1 They should also change the sound (honestly sounds really bad) when someone put a message in chatrooms

Comment: This feature request is rather similar: [Why is there no support for MathJax in chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15041) (However, it is marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).)

Comment: first it's MathJax. If they are smart, raw code won't bother them.

Comment: @Roddy “first it's MathJax” What are you referring to?

Comment: This stackexchange doesn't have full LaTeX. it has the subset called MathJax.

Comment: @Roddy Ok. What do you mean by “raw code won’t bother them”? What does that have to do with smartness? It simply has to do with legibility. Most people prefer rendered code to raw code.

Comment: I don't in most cases. They can understand it just as good raw if competent in it.  it's just as legible either way.. I'm not confident such a bias will exist is in any group of smart people. stupid people will have trouble with it either way.

Comment: @Roddy I wasn’t talking about you, I was talking about most people. “it's just as legible either way..” That’s just objectively false. Were it true, papers would be presented as raw code! Moreover, you’re calling people who prefer rendered code to raw code stupid, which is not only wrong, but also rude and inflammatory.

Comment: pleasing to the eye, is not  legibility. I rest my case.