# MathJax not always rendering tag-question summaries due to early $truncati

Tags: bug, mathjax, tagging

Sometimes the question summaries don’t get all their MathJax rendered. For example, from the [summation tag questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) you see this:

[image: bad math jax rendering demo]

It looks to me like this bug is caused by the truncation of the summaries when that interrupts the MathJax so you no longer have a correctly paired `$....$` sequence to render:

> I have no idea how to even start solving this example. Please, explain the best approach (step-by-step) to this summation with binomial coefficients: $$\sum_{k=j}^n (-1)^k\cdot\binom{n}{k}\cdot...

Comment: Probably the same reason as here: [Post with many lines of display math takes up most of the Questions page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19650). The preview/summary simply takes some number of the first characters of the question, it doesn't matter whether it ends in a middle of MathJax code. (And as far as I can tell, this is completely unrelated to tags.)