# Users who run bots/have developed tools on math.SE

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, user-scripts

Are there any users who run bots/have developed interesting tools for math.SE?

Listing such tools in one post may be good in my opinion, and I am aware of one such user, Normal Human, and it took me 4 months to discover the toolset he developed, which are really useful.

Comment: FYI [there's a whole SE site dedicated to the SE API and apps/scripts/extensions that use it](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, even there, I doubt if there's a way to sort users according to site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the top of my head:

- [Ilmari Karonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9602/ilmari-karonen) is the maintainer of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) that patches various glitches on SE-sites, some specific to this site. See the user page for details.
- [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) has developed a tool, known under the name <strike>CatChase</strike> ChatJax, so that math renders in chat. As far as I know it is widely used, and makes chat a lot more useful for some. See [a meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) or the userpage for a link to the tool.
- [Normal Human](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/normal-human), already mentioned in the question-post, provides a variety of tools that make day-to-day community-moderation tasks simpler as well as data about the site. Those are hosted on http://normalhuman.github.io/, a link to this is presently on the user page.

Comment: ChatJax, as it is colloquially known.

Answer (score 7):

Two bots are active in chat rooms of this site:

- [Unanswered tracker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-341/unanswered-tracker) (run and developed by mixedmath) posts the number of unanswered questions in [The Crusade of Answers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) room.
- [SmokeDetector](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914/smokedetector) (run by Undo, developed by [Charcoal team](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE)) alerts about spam posts in [C.R.U.D.E.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/c-r-u-d-e) room.